# Angular: Remove last letter in string if selectionItems is less than 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How would I remove the last letter in this string if the selectedItems is 1 or less.

```
<p translate translate-values="{value: selectedItems.length | removePlural}">
 TEAMS_EDIT_SELECTED_PLURAL
</p>
```

**Value**

```
 TEAMS_EDIT_SELECTED_PLURAL: 'You have selected {{value}} items.',
```

**Filter**

```
myFilters.filter('removePlural', function($translate) {
    if (selectedItems.length <= 1) {

    } else {

    }
});
```

Comment: if(selectedItems.length <= 1){string.slice(0,-1);}?

Comment: If you're doing what I think you're doing, you might want to look at ng-pluralize http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngPluralize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dskh said in their comment, you should consider using the [ngPluralize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angPluralize) directive.

Simply truncating the string will lead to problems very quickly, for example `daisies` to `daisy` doesn't follow that pattern. Also, if you ever need to make your app work with multiple languages, you're really going to be up a creek.

```
<p ng-pluralize 
   count="selectedItems"
   when="{'0': 'You have note selected any items.',
          'one': 'You have selected one item.',
          'other': 'You have selected {} items.'}">
</p>
```

It would appear that you're using the [ngTranslate module](http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/) (even though you never stated that in your question).  In this case it wouldn't make sense to use the translate filter, you'll need to use the [translate service](http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/docs/en/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.%24translate) in a controller.

```
app.controller("MyController", function($translate) {
  $scope.text = {
    TEAMS_EDIT_SELECTED_PLURAL : $translate("TEAMS_EDIT_SELECTED_PLURAL"),
    TEAMS_EDIT_SELECTED_SINGULAR : $translate("TEAMS_EDIT_SELECTED_SINGULAR"),
    TEAMS_EDIT_SELECTED_NONE : $translate("TEAMS_EDIT_SELECTED_NONE")
  }
});
```

And in your view you can do the following

```
<p ng-pluralize 
   count="selectedItems"
   when="{'0': text.TEAMS_EDIT_SELECTED_NONE,
          'one': text.TEAMS_EDIT_SELECTED_SINGULAR,
          'other': text.TEAMS_EDIT_SELECTED_PLURAL }">
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My view is showing "text.TEAMS_EDIT_SELECTED_NONE" instead of the translation. Any ideas?